# Создание счетчика количество пользователй

Tags: php, python, node.js

Есть идея создать сайт, и у меня такой вопрос, как можно реализовать счетчик количество пользователей на сайте, а также счетчик количество пользователей online?

Comment: Эм, как числа. Какие проблемы с этим у вас возникли, что вам непонятно?

Comment: Ну к примеру : вот у меня есть форма регистрации, и после того, как пользователь регистрируется на моем сайте, что-бы отображалось online он или нет у других пользователь, а также что-бы отображалось количество пользователей на сайте! То есть, что-бы другие пользователи видели, сколько в данный момент есть пользователей на сайте!

Comment: добавьте к таблице пользователей к примеру поле `is_Active`, и при входе на сайт ставьте её значение в true. А чтобы остальные пользователи видели количество онлайн, просто выводите всех пользователей у которых это поле стоит в true

Comment: И все это нужно делать через phpMyAdmin? то есть, true будет считать количество пользователей ориентируясь на последнего зарегистрированного пользователя?

Comment: не зарегистрированного, а авторизированного

Comment: А как сделать так, что-бы она считала количество зарегистрированных пользователей?

Comment: зарегистрированных? достать всех пользователей и подсчитать count()

Comment: То есть, count() прописывать в phpMtAdmin? Или count() мы прописываем в файле с .php ?

Comment: php, когда достаете